# How to center a table that in form at middle

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to the table goes vertically down
I tried using `verticle-align:middle` and still dont get the job done
[image: Currently]
**Expected:(Editted using paint)**
[image: Editted using paint]
**register.html**

```
<div class='center'>
        <form method='post' autocomplete="off">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td width='200px'>Username</td>
                    <td><input id='rounded' type='text' name='user'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Passwords</td>
                    <td><input id='rounded' type='password' name='pass'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td><input id='rounded' type='text' name='name'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td><input id='rounded' type='text' name='email'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>No. Telephone</td>
                    <td><input id='rounded' type='text' name='tel'></td>
                </tr>
            </table><br>
            <input id='button' type='submit' value='enter' formmethod='post' >
        </form>
    </div>
```

**register.css**

```
.center{
  text-align: center;
}

form{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

table{
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

My Approah is to use empty row of `table` , but im sure `css` gotta be good than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
form{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: i was going to post this.. lol

Comment: Yea , but the `button` also `centered` and being placed right to the `table`

Comment: Um , nevermind , i think that will be a `bug` that will be a `feature` because that's kinda nice..add some spaces and that will look cool